# How to compare different format string as date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have field a VARCHAR field`dob` in mysql table where dates are saved in two format :

> 1> y-m-d
>   2> d/m/y

Now I want to select candidates whose `dob <= '01/01/1979' (born on or before 01 January, 1979)`

but i am unable to understand how to compare these two time formats at once.

is there any way to handle this like either convert one format into another format and then compare.

Comment: Perhaps take the time to fix this problem by creating a new DATETIME column and updating it with the string values converted to a DATETIME.

Comment: how you can choice between the two format ??

Comment: You should fix the data. But if you can't: `where coalesce(date(dob), str_to_date(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')) <= '1979-01-01'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current table design is bad because the `dob` column is:

- storing date information as text, and on top of this
- storing two different date formats in the same column

You absolutely should fix this long term by storing your date information in a proper date/time column.

Here is one temporary workaround:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    (dob LIKE '%-%' AND STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%Y-%m-%d') < '1979-01-01') OR
    (dob LIKE '%/%' AND STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y') < '1979-01-01');
```

Answer (score 1):

I almost hate to write this code, but...

```
...
where str_to_date(dob, if(dob like '%/%', '%d/%m/%y', '%y-%m-%d')) <= '01/01/1970'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [IFNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp) and [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) on the two date formats:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE(col_, '%Y-%m-%d'), STR_TO_DATE(col_, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS 'my_date'
    , col_
FROM
    date_test
WHERE 
    IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE(col_, '%Y-%m-%d'), STR_TO_DATE(col_, '%m/%d/%Y')) <= '1979-01-01';
```